# My code crashes Elementor for me easily (WP + PHP )

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a code for a loop but it disrupts everything for me, I have a file
file.php that is inside my template (let's say it's called test)

Now I call the file from the function (function file by include_once ('file.php'); )

Now it works, but my elementor display is broken and I can't update anything, and it also ruins my main pages, but the post pages look great

```
<?php
function video() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">';
    
    
    $x = 1;
    $number = get_field_object('number');



    echo '<div class="col-lg-2-1">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="video"><iframe src="" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" name="slider1"></iframe></div>
        <span class="kfir">';

        while($x <= $number['value']) {
            $prak = 'video '.$x;
            $num = 'chapter_'.$x;
            $chapter1 = get_field_object($num);
        
                echo '<a href="'.$chapter1['value'].'" target="slider1"><div class="text">'.$prak.'</div></a>';
        
        
          $x++;
        } 

    echo '
    </span>
    </div>
</div>';
    
 

}

add_shortcode('video_live', 'video');

?>
```

Does anyone know where my mistake is?
And can someone guide me how to make it work only within the posts pages?

Comment: What would happen if the variable `$number` is empty or null?

Comment: It will make a loop that doesn't end, for example there is a number on the page and I want this loop to reach the number I chose, it will do and do and do until it stops in example 3, it works but it knocks out the elements in WordPress

Comment: From my experiences,  in order to find out where the bug is, we should narrow the code down. For instance, you can comment line by line to figure out where the bug is.

Comment: Well I tried everything but it doesn't work as if I have a problem my display says something in red JSON